# Basemap quality map library for C++

Tags: python, c++, visualization, matplotlib-basemap

Is there any map library available for C++ that produces python's [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) quality results? My interest in this is primarily driven by slowness of basemap, because despite its great output, it is very very slow for high-resolution contour plotting.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c

Comment: @MathieuRodic That's an interesting solution. My intention of exploring a C++ library is primarily speed. I find basemap to be very slow. So it would be my expectation that calling the python library from C++ wouldn't solve that problem. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: if you are concerned by speed, please make it clear in your question. The answers will be more suitable to your needs if you state those.

Comment: Also, `basemap` has been written in C (see https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap). Maybe a direct binding would be more efficient.

Comment: I know basemap is written in C, but I wasn't sure how much could be gained by a direct binding. I'll definitely give it a try.